# Best way to do multiple table associations in a LINQ dbml file?

Tags: database, linq-to-sql

I have a couple of tables in my database, one called **Task**, and another called **User**.  The Task table has two columns **CreatedBy** and **ModifiedBy** that map to the **UserId** column in the User table.

I want to add the User table to the dbml file and add the associations.  I notice now that when I look at class I have two properties one called **User** and the other called **User1**.  I would rather have it say **CreatedByUser** and **ModifiedByUser**.

Should I just go in an modify the properties or is it better to bring the table into the dbml file twice and rename it to what I would look.

Just wondering what the best way to do this would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the properties.  These really are just properties and it's ok to link them back to the same table.